# Android SmsManger Delivery report

Tags: android, smsmanager

I send multiple message to multiple contact, and for each contact use following code

```
private void sendSMS(String first, String last, String id, String phoneNumber)
{        
    try {
        String message;
        message = insertName(first, last);

        if (message.equals(null) || message.equals("")) message = "\n";


        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
            {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {

                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
            {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

i want to find out deliver report for each message, how can get number or any thing of broadcast message to understand delivery report is for this contact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create your delivered pending intent with an extra that you will use to identify the message sent.

```
Intent deliveredIntent = new Intent(DELIVERED + id); 
deliveredIntent.putExtra("id", id); // Add some unique id as an extra
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
       deliveredIntent, 0);

registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
            {
                lonng messageID = arg1.getLongExtra("id", -1L);
                if(id!=-1)
                 {
                      // you got your sms delivered with the id
                 }

            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED+id));
```

Comment: Yes you can set anything as long as you are able to identify intents from each other.

Comment: 'id' has been defined as String within parameters; that is 'putExtra()' adds a string to 'deliveredIntent'. Then why do you use 'getLongExtra()' instead of 'getStringExtra()' in 'onReceive'?

Comment: @Tarun any idea about MMS ?

Comment: @Tarun : How can I get default message app SMS delivery report.