# DELPHI XE5 How send SMS with delivery notification in ANDROID

Tags: android, delphi

I know how to send sms from Android. It's very simple:

```
var   
  smsTo: JString;
  smsManager: JSmsManager;
begin
  smsManager := TJSmsManager.JavaClass.getDefault;
  smsTo := StringToJString('number_xxx');
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsTo, nil, StringToJString('Test SMS'), nil, nil);
```

**But the question is: How to send sms with delivery recipient? Is it possible in Delphi XE5?**

Thanks for your answers.
George

Comment: Have you seen the documentation? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

Comment: This may be helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891486/broadcast-receivers-in-delphi-xe5-android?rq=1

Comment: @Pateman: maybe you can give a short abstract and some copy+paste from your links, with the relevant parts. Then we can vote that answer up. These external links might disappear after a while...

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> Parameters
>
> - **`destinationAddress`**   the address to send the message to
> - **`scAddress`**    is the service center address or null to use the current default SMSC
> - **`text`** the body of the message to send
> - **`sentIntent`**   if not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the message is successfully sent, or failed. The result code will be
>     Activity.RESULT_OK for success, or one of these errors:
>     RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF
>     RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU. The per-application based SMS control checks
>     sentIntent. If sentIntent is NULL the caller will be checked against
>     all unknown applications, which cause smaller number of SMS to be sent
>     in checking period.
> - **`deliveryIntent`**   if not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the message is delivered to the recipient. The raw pdu of the status
>     report is in the extended data ("pdu").

You're clearly missing the last two parameters in your code.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224801/android-smsmanger-delivery-report) how to do that in Java - it's pretty straightforward, but Delphi makes in a bit harder for us. Have a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891486/broadcast-receivers-in-delphi-xe5-android?rq=1). The most interesting thing is [the first link](http://www.pclviewer.com/android/androidJNI.html) in the answer.

Basically you need to use the JNI wrapper to communicate with Java classes directly, because Delphi doesn't expose the functionality needed here - at least I'm not aware of anything.

Good luck!